# PHP add elements together but not Maths

Tags: php, string

I am trying to add a series of numbers to a string, but not add them up. The following code is adding the numbers up and giving me the result. I want it to simple add them to the string.

```
<?php foreach ($directions as $direct) {

    $latitude = $direct->start_location->lat; 
    $longitude = $direct->start_location->lng;  

    $dircords += $latitude.','.$longitude.'|';

    }?><?php echo $dircords?>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.=` instead of `+=`.

`.` is the string concatenation operator. `+` is for additions.

See [String operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).